# How to pass a list from a view to template in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying pass to list from a view to template in Django.

In my file wiew.py I define the view named hour

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

# Create your views here.
def hour(request):
now = datetime.now()
list = ['Bern','Bob','Eufronio','Epifanio','El pug']
return render_to_response('hour.html',list)
```

I'm using shorcuts in my view.

I have a template named hour.html so this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Date</title>

</head>
<body>
    The names are:
    {%for item in list%}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

But my template hour.html is showed empty in the browser. How to can I send the list from my view to template. Thanks for tour attention

Answer (score 7):

You should use `return render_to_response('hour.html',{"list": list})`

Or `return render(request, 'hour.html', {"list": list})`

The second `render` need `from django.shortcuts import render`

Comment: Perfect, It works. This mean that I can pass any python objects but always inside of a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

`list` is a python built-in sequence type, you should avoid using generic names for you variable names to avoid conflicts. You can read more about Python's built-in types [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list).

For this however, you just need to pass in the context:

```
return render_to_response('hour.html', {"list": list})
```

Comment: Hi Drewness, thanks for your information, although I've changed the name to myList and this doesn't work for me. The render_to_response function can send python objects?

Comment: Yes, it can pass any irritable. List, dict, etc.