# Displaying image onto django web directly from static directory

Tags: django

Is there a way I can read and display my images from the static directory using bootstrap? eg. display **multiple**(100) images which I can delete and add new batches with different file name..

I want to avoid doing ,

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    ...
    <img src={% static '../a.jpg' %} 
     class="img-responsive"><img src={% static '../b.jpg' %} 
     class="img-responsive">...
```

solved!
reference can be found here
[Passing a python list to django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761173/passing-a-python-list-to-django-template) &
[How to pass a list from a view to template in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108082/how-to-pass-a-list-from-a-view-to-template-in-django)

Comment: Why can't you just do the same thing multiple times, or in a loop, for multiple images? No, using php would not be a good way to solve your problem since it can be easily solved using the tools you already have, ie Django.

Comment: So, you want to display all images that are in a particular directory?

Comment: @ChidG Could you provide an example for multiple images? noted about php, thanks! and yes, onto the Django web directly

Comment: `<img src={% static 'visual/images/a.jpg' %}><img src={% static 'visual/images/b.jpg' %} ><img src={% static 'visual/images/c.jpg' %} >`

Comment: @ChidG if I have 100 images. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, using a loop. `{% for image in images %}<img src={% static image %}>{% endfor %}`, where images is a context variable pointing to an list of filenames. Your next question is going to be how do you generate that list of filenames, right? You do it in the view, using the `os` module.

Comment: @ChidG please provide an example if u can

Comment: Yes, that's the right direction, but it's not exactly correct. This is really a separate question and if you Google 'python get list of all files in directory' or something similar you should find results. This is technically trivial, the challenge for you is learning how to ask the right questions.

Answer (score 0):

you should get list of image's names to array then using loop for create the image im html Django template.

```
myList=['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'] 
parse mylist parameter to Django template then using for loop to generate image tag.
{% for img in mylist %}
 <img src={% URL::asset('folder_storage/'+img) %} class="img-responsive">
{% endfor %}
```

It's same method in PHP.

Comment: The question is about Django templates, not blade templates.

Comment: it's for Django! just mistake on typing!

Comment: @nhựtnguyễn thanks but how do you parse mylist parameter to Django template?

Comment: @nhựtnguyễn, `{% URL::asset('folder_storage/'+img) %}` is not Django template syntax.

Comment: it should be
 `{% load staticfiles%}
 <img src='{% static 'assets/img/'+img %}' />`